# Gmap3 applying a new center postion without destroying the whole map

Tags: google-maps, jquery-gmap3

I am hacking around with gmap3 managing to get the first task working. Showing the map using a lat long.

My javascript look likes

```
  $('#map_canvas').gmap3(
                    {
                        action: 'init',
                        options: {
                            center: [x,y],
                            zoom: 12,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                                mapTypeIds: []
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        action: 'addMarkers',
                        radius: 100,
                        markers: GetMarkers(),
                        clusters:
                        {
                            0:
                                {
                                    content: '<div class="cluster cluster-3">CLUSTER_COUNT <div class="cluster-3text">Stops</div> </div>',
                                    width: 66,
                                    height: 65
                                }
                        },
                        marker:
                        {
                            options:
                            {
                                icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('../img/marker.png', size, origin, null, null)
                            },
                            events:
                            {
                                mouseover: function (marker, event, data) {
                                                                        getArrivalsAndStop(marker, event, data);
                                },
                                mouseout: function () {
                                    $(this).gmap3({ action: 'clear', name: 'overlay' });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

This loads the map how I want. My next step is to be able apply a new lat & long. How can I do this without destroying the whole map and recreating it everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation:](http://gmap3.net/documentation.html)

> This example executes map.setCenter with the result of the address resolution, target is not specified because this is the map.

```
$('#test').gmap3(
{ 
  action: 'getLatLng',
  address: '2 bis rue saint antoine, eguilles',
  callback: function(result){
    if (result){
      $(this).gmap3({action: 'setCenter', args:[ result[0].geometry.location ]});
    } else {
      alert('Bad address 2 !');
    }
  }
```

});

So it looks like if you know the coordinates and don't need to use the geocoder, it would be:

```
     $(this).gmap3({action: 'setCenter', args:[ new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude) ]});
```

Comment: I tried to use setCenter, but nothing happens, the same for action : 'addMarker' any ideas (I just copied your last line of code changing $('#map") and latitude and longitude manually filled.

Answer (score 9):

I am using [jquery gmap3 plugin](http://gmap3.net/en/).

If you want to call setCenter after having initialized the map and without reloading the whole thing you can do this like this :

```
$('#mymap').gmap3('get').setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(48.706685,-3.486694899999975))
```

$('#mymap').gmap3('get') is the magic thing here, it give you the real google map object I think.

It was hard for me to find this out so I hope it can help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of late in the game, but I am using a list and map(google maps type). hope it helps

Here is how I achieved it

```
$(document).delegate('#inner_list li', 'click', function () {
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');




$("#map-canvas").gmap3({
    get: {
        name:"marker",
        id: id,
        all: true,
            callback: function(objs){
                $.each(objs, function(i, obj){
                obj.setIcon("http://www.markericon.com");
                var newLL = obj.getPosition()
                $('#map-canvas').gmap3('get').panTo(newLL)


                });
            }
  }
});
```

});